# Extracting a subfolder from (GNU)tar archive

Tags: wildcard, tar

What is the right spell to extract a subfolder from a tar archive when you do not know the base name?

I have a tar archive with the following structure:

```
myarchive.tar
  |
  +-- StrangeName_Including_variable_parts
        |
        +-- bin
        |     |
        |     +-- Uninteresting_stuff
        |
        +-- src
              |
              +-- Stuff
              |
              +-- I_need
```

My problem is to extract "src" and put it somewhere on my disk regardless of the name of base directory (StrangeName_Including_variable_parts).

I tried something like:

```
tar xf myarchive.tar -C destination src
```

But it doesn't seem to do what I need.

What I would need is:

```
destination
  |
  +-- src
        |
        +-- Stuff
        |
        +-- I_need
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract with wildcard:

```
tar -xf myarchive.tar -C destination --wildcards '*/src'
```

See: `man tar`